# .svg images not showing

Tags: html, svg, cdn

I have a very weird error that occurs with SVG images:

```
<img src="https://faviconer.net/img/arrow-right-dark.svg" alt="Next">
```

Here is an example.

While the image is available when viewing it directly, it doesn't display when used as a "src" for an image from a different domain. It's true for any .svg images. PNG, GIF, JPEG and other images are fine.

Faviconer net runs through Clouldflare CDN. Could that be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid the question being closed or more down votes, put the relevant code here, and do not link off to another site.

Comment: I've replaced your svg image with a different one and it works. Maybe it's the image. You may try to use an svg image sved at icons8. Alternatively you may use inline svg.

Comment: Yes, the very same image shows fine if it's placed to the same domain. This is the problem - I want it on another domain and I want to know for the future reference what the reason for the problem is

Answer (score 0):

It appears that having incorrect content type in the header makes a browser unable to identify an svg image as image (unlike other image types). So it has to have content type:

image/svg+xml